# The non-functional number

Tags: group-theory, functions

Lets say $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=3,$ and $f(4)=n$. Some rules to follow are that:

$1)$ $f(x)$ could literally be any function and it depends on what $n$ is.

2) $n$ is an integer.

3) If there is an integer for which no function could work, then that integer is put in group A.

4) $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=3$ for all functions $f(x)$

For $n=4,f(x)=x$

For $n=2, f(x)=[2\sin(x-1.2)+1]$

And so on...

How many $n$ values are in group A? Can we prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every $n$ has a possible function: 
$$f_n(x)=x+(n-4)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)/6$$